# How do I solve the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've just started solving 2-variable limits and I'm stuck at one of the examples:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)}$$

How do I approach limits like that? I've been thinking on it for quite a long time and I don't know what could I possibly do. Intuition (which may be wrong) tells me that this limit exists and is equal to $0$ because of the nominator, but as I said - I don't seem to find any way to solve it.

Comment: There is certainly trouble if $y=0$. Even if we do not allow that, we can let $y$ approach $0$ rapidly, say $y=x^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Could you explain further what can I do with that information?

Comment: With that replacement, we get $\frac{1-\cos(x^2+x^4)}{x^8(1+x^2)}$. But the top behaves like $x^4$, so the thing blows up. Actually, $x=y$ already does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polar coordinates you get:

$$\ \lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{1-\cos(\rho^2)}{\rho^4\cdot\rho^2\cdot\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{1-\cos(\rho^2)}{\rho^4}\cdot\frac{1}{\rho^2\cdot\sin^2(\theta)\cdot\cos^2(\theta)}=$$

$$=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\rho^2\cdot\sin^2(\theta)\cdot\cos^2(\theta)}=\lim_{\rho\to0}\frac{2}{\rho^2\cdot\sin^2(2\theta)}$$

Now, since $\forall \text{ }\theta ≠(2k+1)\frac{π}{2}$ you have that: $|\frac{2}{\rho^2\cdot\sin^2(2\theta)}|≥|\frac{2}{\rho^2}|\to\infty$ , then your limit is divergent too.